# Error 404 when I make a request to the API in http://localhost:5000

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am carrying out a project in MERN Stack and when making the request to the Api it returns a 404 error.

I do not know what it can be since the server works correctly, the strange thing is that sometimes when lifting it if it works without touching anything but other times it does not and I do not know how to solve it.

Another curious fact is that when raising the servers of other projects that were working correctly, I get the same error.

Error on Google Chrome DevTools:
[image of error in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRYGV.png)

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/justwatch',{useNewUrlParser:true})
    .catch(e=>console.log('Connection error:',e.message))

const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('MongoDB MOVIES database connection successfully');
})

const movieRouter = require('./routes/movie')
const seriesRouter = require('./routes/serie')

app.use('/movies',movieRouter)
app.use('/series',seriesRouter)

app.listen(port,()=>{console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)})
```

Router:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
let Movie = require('../models/movie.model')

router.route('/movies').get((req,res)=>{

let limite = parseInt(req.params.number)

Movie.find().limit(12)
    .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})

router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{

Movie.find().limit(12)
        .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
        .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})
module.exports = router
```

React requests:

```js
const getMovies = async() => { 
    await axios.get('localhost:5000/movies/')
            .then(res=>{ console.log(res.data); setMovies(res.data) }) 
            .catch(err=>console.log(err)) console.log(movies) }
```

Comment: have you tested your server with `postman` or `cURL` ?

Comment: Could you show us the react-side requests ?

Comment: @R.LM yes i tested with postman but i get the same result, i can't connect with the database. It is possible that the error is in the port ??

Comment: It might be that but it can be anything, show us the react part of the code (only the http requests parts)

Comment: then where do you get your `404` from ?

Comment: @R.LM this is the react-side request `  const getMovies = async() =>{ 
        await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/movies/')
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data);
                setMovies(res.data) 
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        console.log(movies)
    }`

Comment: @R.LM from Google Chrome DevTools > Network

Comment: You are not using await the right way here, you should either treat the request as a `Promise` or as the response in an `async` function. therefore, getMovies does not return anything. but this shall not be the problem here

Comment: can you send a picture of the error ?

Comment: @R.LM how can I send a picture ?? Sorry i'm rookie here.

Comment: whenyou edit your answer, at the top of the canvas you have icons, one of them is a picture icon allowing you to embed a photo

Comment: @R.LM okey thanks, I upload an image of error

Comment: do you have the error message @ricmiber96 in console (not network tab)